# Outer Join One table with result of Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to add dummy timestamps for distinct days in a table from timestamps that are already present in the table.

I know that I can use outer Join to accomplish this but I haven't succeded so far. Still confused on how to do this. This is what I came up with so far

```
     SELECT time_stamp from tbl   
 OUTER JOIN y
 SELECT y.time_stamp =
       SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM tbl ORDER BY DATE(time_stamp) ASC
```

The original table will look something like this

```
timestamp           phase_1 phase_2 phase_3
2014-03-04 12:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 02:00:00   0       0        0
2014=03-06 01:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-07 00:00:00   0       0        0
```

The result from the query should be something like this

```
timestamp           phase_1 phase_2 phase_3
2014-03-04 00:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-04 12:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 00:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 02:00:00   0       0        0
2014=03-06 00:00:00   0       0        0
2014=03-06 01:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-07 00:00:00   0       0        0
```

I know that it can be done using the OUTER JOIN query but I can't figure out how. Maybe there is a better way of doing this too.

Comment: are you trying to INSERT into a table? or just present some additional rows in a query?

Comment: I am trying to insert them the timestamps of particular days to make sure that there is atleast one timestamp for one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a way to include each DATE (at 00:00:00) unless that date (at 00:00:00) already exists.

```
select
        `timestamp`
      , phase_1
      , phase_2
      , phase_3
from table1

union

select
        date(`timestamp`)
      , phase_1
      , phase_2
      , phase_3
from table1

order by 
        `timestamp`
```

It is "truncating" each `timestamp` to a date, then by using UNION all duplicates are removed.

so, From this:

```
timestamp           phase_1 phase_2 phase_3
2014-03-04 12:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 02:00:00   0       0        0
2014=03-06 01:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-07 00:00:00   0       0        0
```

It will produce this

```
timestamp           phase_1 phase_2 phase_3
2014-03-04 00:00:00   0       0        0     --<< new
2014-03-04 12:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 00:00:00   0       0        0     --<< new
2014-03-05 02:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-06 00:00:00   0       0        0     --<< new
2014-03-06 01:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-07 00:00:00   0       0        0
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c743a4/2

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, sorry for my mistake in the question

Comment: what should i do if i want only 0 values for phase_1,2 and 3 ?

Comment: if you only want 0 v alues for the phases either: a, leave them out of the query completely, or use zero as a constant for all of the phases, (both the upper and lower halves of the union)

Comment: Thanks, I figured that one out. Silly question

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT time_stamp from tbl   
 OUTER JOIN y
 SELECT y.time_stamp in(
       SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM tbl ORDER BY DATE(time_stamp) ASC )
```

one of the best way using 'IN'